# labelling polygon by clicking on polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I would like to check if it is possible to have some sort of dynamic labelling of the polygon shapefile by clicking on selected polygon within this shapefile. Is this possible on the QGIS gui? 
For example, I will have a base map + my generated sets of polygon layer. I would like to easily label this polygon layer by just clicking on polygons on the layer on the GUI. All the clicked polygon are labelled the same way.

Comment: I think you should use your good description as a feature request within the QGIS project, I will vote it up!

Comment: ok will do that! Is it a very common for your use cases to have this features? @Marco

Comment: I did not get your question completelly, but guessing, it is common for me to need the feature you describe, I have never found something similar.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to label only clicked features you can **define a (python) action** enabling you to change one of the attributes of your feature's table.
Then you can define a **rule-based styling** of your layer using that changed attribute ...

You can even define a "back"-action unlabeling your feature "on click" ...